# How do I add a string to a Django template?

Tags: css, django, templates, inline

I want to take this piece of code...

```
<section data-name="color1" data-type="color" data-order="2" style="color:{{ block.color1|default:"inherit" }}">
```

Which by default outputs this tag in the html...

```
<section data-name="color1" data-type="color" data-order="2" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

Because of a color conflict on one of my child elements, the color of the block.color1 variable isn't being applied. I'd like to add an "!important" to the inline CSS's output to counter this issue. In other words, I want an output of

```
<section data-name="color1" data-type="color" data-order="2" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;">
```

in the HTML. What can I add to Django to ensure I receive an output with !important in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another filter, assuming the first one returns a string:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def mark_important(value):
    return value.replace(';', '!important;')
```

in the template:

```
<section data-name="color1" data-type="color" data-order="2" style="color:{{ block.color1|default:"inherit"|mark_important }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add a class to the section:

```
<section data-name="color1" data-type="color" data-order="2" class="{{ foo }}">
```

Then in your css:

```
.foo {
   color:someColor !important;
}
```